# The end timestamp of an event-time window cannot become earlier than the current watermark by merging

Tags: apache-flink, amazon-kinesis

We have created a streaming Flink application which is running in AWS Kinesis Analytics. It is mainly used to process web click stream data (page views, sessionization, etc.). We have an input of page views from a Kinesis Data Stream which is split into keyed windows (keyed by a session/device token).

The application runs fine at a small scale, but when scaled up for testing at what we expect to be a normal production throughput (~1 million page views per day) we are periodically encountering an error when merging windows:

```
“The end timestamp of an event-time window cannot become earlier than the current watermark by merging.”
```

This UnsupportedOperationException is crashing our application, and when it restarts, it tries to process the same window again and crashes, over and over again. We’ve traced this exception to the following PR (https://github.com/apache/flink/pull/3587) but we are at a bit of a loss for how to handle this case. Our main goal is to prevent the application from crashing or for the state of the application to be corrupted in any way.

We have tried changing the maxOutOfOrderness around to see if the application behaves differently but have yet to find a scenario where the error doesn't occur, except when we have set it to a very low number like 1.

```
/Create input data streams from kinesis data streams
    DataStream<String> pvInput;

    if (env.getIsLocal()) {
        pvInput = createLocalDataStream(streamEnv, "pv-stream", env);
    } else {
        pvInput = createAwsDataStream(streamEnv, env.get("pv-stream"), env);
    }

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

/* SOURCES AND INITIAL MAPPING */

    //Turn pageview strings into pageview objects and assign timestamps
    DataStream<PageView> mappedPvs = pvInput
            .map(value -> mapper.readValue(value, PageView.class)).uid("pv_mapper").name("PV Mapper")
            .filter(value -> value.timestamp != null && value.uuid != null).uid("pv_filter").name("PV Filter")
            .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor<PageView>(Time.minutes(30)) {
                @Override
                public long extractTimestamp(PageView element) {
                    return element.timestamp.getTime();
                }
            }).uid("pv_timestamp_assigner").name("PV Timestamps");

/* SESSIONIZATION */

    //Key Pageviews by uuid for sessionization
    KeyedStream<PageView, String> keyedPvStream = mappedPvs
            .keyBy((KeySelector<PageView, String>) value -> value.uuid);

    long sessionWindow = 30L;

    //Window pageviews into sessions
    DataStream<PageViewAccumulator> sessionized = keyedPvStream
        .window(ActivitySessionAssigner.withGap(Time.minutes(sessionWindow)))
        .aggregate(new PageViewAggregateFunction()).uid("session_window").name("Session Window");
```

Expected results are that the result of merging windows would never result in end time stamps earlier than the current watermark.

Actual results are that they do occur, leading to the following exception:

```
{
    "locationInformation": "org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph.transitionState(ExecutionGraph.java:1384)",
    "logger": "org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph",
    "message": "Failure type is SYSTEM on RUNNING -> FAILING.",
    "throwableInformation": [
        "java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The end timestamp of an event-time window cannot become earlier than the current watermark by merging. Current watermark: 1555506438433 window: TimeWindow{start=1555455813013, end=1555457829192}",
        "\tat org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.operators.windowing.WindowOperator$2.merge(WindowOperator.java:320)",
        "\tat org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.operators.windowing.WindowOperator$2.merge(WindowOperator.java:311)",
        "\tat org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.operators.windowing.MergingWindowSet.addWindow(MergingWindowSet.java:212)",
        "\tat org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.operators.windowing.WindowOperator.processElement(WindowOperator.java:311)",
        "\tat org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamInputProcessor.processInput(StreamInputProcessor.java:202)",
        "\tat org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OneInputStreamTask.run(OneInputStreamTask.java:105)",
        "\tat org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:300)",
        "\tat org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:711)",
        "\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)"
    ],
    "threadName": "flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-16170",
    "applicationARN": "arn:aws:kinesisanalytics:us-xxx-x:XXXXXXXXXXXXX:application/XXXXX",
    "applicationVersionId": "6",
    "messageSchemaVersion": "1",
    "messageType": "INFO"
}
```

Comment: Have you tried making the watermarking delay larger than the session gap -- e.g., 31 minutes?

Comment: We have not, only tried same and less. We will give that a try and share the results here.

Comment: Tried it with 31 @DavidAnderson, but we got the same error message. It might be worth noting that in this test data, there can be some pretty significant delays in data entering the pipeline. This last failure had a watermark time of Tuesday, April 16, 2019 7:44:51.031 AM and the end time of the merged window was Tuesday, April 16, 2019 6:14:37.667 AM, a little over 1h30m difference.

Comment: I can't explain why such an old window hasn't been purged before attempting this problematic merge, but I think you should be able to avoid this problem by either (1) increasing the watermark delay to the point where there are no late events; (2) increasing allowed lateness to accommodate the actual lateness; or (3) using a process function to filter out late events.

Comment: Thanks Dave we're baffled as well, we will look into those approaches and see if we can work this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem can be fixed by filtering late events with a ProcessFunction like the one below.  Placing this function between the timestamp extractor and the window function removes any late events eliminating the possibility for this error to occur.

```
public class LateEventFilter extends ProcessFunction<PageView, PageView> {
    @Override
    public void processElement(PageView value, Context ctx, Collector<PageView> out) throws Exception {
        if(ctx.timestamp() > ctx.timerService().currentWatermark()){
            out.collect(value);
        }
    }
}
```

You can also use a similar function to output the late events to a sink like the example below.

```
public class LateEventSideOutput extends ProcessFunction<PageView, PageView> {
    @Override
    public void processElement(PageView value, Context ctx, Collector<PageView> out) throws Exception {
        if(ctx.timestamp() <= ctx.timerService().currentWatermark()) {
            out.collect(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Wiring it all up would look something like this:

```
DataStream<PageView> lateFilteredPvs = mappedPvs.process(new LateEventFilter()).uid("late_pv_filter").name("LatePvFilter");

DataStream<PageView> latePvs = mappedPvs.process(new LateEventSideOutput()).uid("late_pv").name("LatePv");
                l 
latePvs.addSink(latePvSink).uid("late_pv_sink").name("LatePvSink");
```

Comment: Andrew is an engineer on our team and implemented this based on a suggestion from @DavidAnderson. So thanks David!